# MySQL is not starting

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

When my XAMPP Apache is starting, while I start MYSQL the following error is occurring:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: "Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums."

Comment: 2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1278 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

Comment: 2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1600694 and 1600694 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 3298055 in the ib_logfiles!
2014-04-18 12:22:25 1472 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got `Skype` or `teamviewer` Quit it and restart your `wamp` server this might help.
Please do post `logs`

Comment: I tried quitting Skype and teamviewer and restarted the Xampp. But  MySQL is not starting. Do I need to change any port number?

Comment: Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums

Comment: I have added the log. Can you help me on this error?